# Schedule PrimeFaces 6.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, schedule

After that I changed the primefaces version to 6.1, my schedule doesn't work correctly, now there is an area under the original area. My events keep working, but I need to correct the difference.Another problem that came with the new version is columnFormat stopped to apply.

```
<p:schedule value="SheduleModel"
 widgetVar="schedule_02"
 id="schedule_02"
 editable="true"
 maxTime="23:00"
 minTime="6:00"
 aspectRatio="2"
 allDaySlot="false"
 axisFormat="H:mm"
 timeFormat="H:mm"
 leftHeaderTemplate="prev,today,next"
 centerHeaderTemplate="title"
 clientTimezone='local’
 columnFormat="month:‘ddd’,week:‘dddd dd/MM’,day:‘dddd dd/MM’"
 rightHeaderTemplate="agendaDay,agendaWeek,month"
 draggable="true"
 resizable=“false”>
</p:schedule>
```

[My Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL7IC.png)

Comment: I once had a similar issue, it was due a jQuery error in the primefaces library for this version. Check your browser console to see what's wrong. My fix was using version 6.0 instead.

Comment: The problem is that all the browsers where we executed it, don't show anyone error. Searching about this error, I founded the same situation but without a final fix.